# C# Custom Serialization - Using TypeConverter

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, viewstate

So I need to serialize a generic dictionary like `Dictionary<long, List<MyClass>>`.  I need to serialize it to store it in the ViewState of an ASP.Net application.

I found an example of using `TypeConverter` to convert my class to a string to be serialized, but I get an error message saying `MyClass is not marked as serializable`.

Here is the code for my class..

```
 [TypeConverter (typeof(MyClass_Converter))]
 public class MyClass
 {
     // some properties
 }

 public class MyClass_Converter : System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter
 {
     public override bool CanConvertTo(...)
     {
         // code
     }

     // CanConvertFrom, ConvertFrom, ConvertTo methods
 }
```

Then when I want to serialize it, I am using this code...

```
 LosFormatter los = new LosFormatter();
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 los.Serialize(sw, hiddenData);
 String resultSt = sw.GetStringBuilder().ToString();   
 ViewState["HiddenData"] = resultSt;
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the `[Serializable]` attribute to your class.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serializableattribute.aspx

Comment: So do I even need to use TypeConverter?

Comment: Try it and find out, then tell us what happens.

Comment: I did, and I didn't see any different when using them together vs. just using Serializable.